# Print statement printing infinitely

Tags: python, printing, while-loop

```
password=input("Please enter your chosen password within 8 and 24 letters: ")
while len(password)>8 and len(password)<24:
    print("this password is within the given length range")
else:
    password=input("Please enter a password within the boundaries: ")
```

When I run the code and the length of the entered password is more than 8 and 24, it just prints "This password is within the given length range" infinitely.
Im not good at coding and im sure ive done something wrong.

Comment: `while`? Why `while`?

Comment: Please learn the basic concepts of programming before you post to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `break` statement to stop the loop. And the loop statement has problems, mainly that you are missing the `if` part of the `else`.

```
password=input("Please enter your chosen password within 8 and 24 letters: ")
while True:                                   #will continue until break statement executes
    if len(password)>8 and len(password)<24:
        print("this password is within the given length range")
        break                                                                #Quit the loop
    else:
        password=input("Please enter a password within the boundaries: ")
```

The above code will run until the user enters a password of `8 < length < 24` .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continually prompt them for a password you'll need your prompt inside your while loop like this and change the less than and greater than signs around.

```
password = ""
while len(password) < 8 or len(password) > 24:
    password = input("Please enter your chosen password within 8 and 24 letters: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `else` only executes after you exit the `while` loop using `break` (as opposed to when the condition becomes false). You simply want

```
password=input("Please enter your chosen password within 8 and 24 letters: ")
while len(password) < 8 or len(password) > 24:
    password=input("Please enter a password within the boundaries: ")
```

If you don't mind using the same prompt for both inputs, use an infinite loop with an explicit break:

```
while True:
    password=input("Please enter your chosen password within 8 and 24 letters: ")
    if 8 <= len(password) <= 24:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You store a valid password in the 'password' variable. The while loop checks if 'password' is valid, confirms that it is, and it keeps on going. You want your loop to keep on going if the user type an invalid password, rather than a valid one. Try:

```
password=input("Please enter your chosen password within 8 and 24 letters: ")
while len(password)<8 or len(password)>24:
    password=input("Please enter a password within the boundaries: ")     

print("this password is within the given length range")
```